# matplotlib not working in Pycharm 4.5.3

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to run a simple code in `Pycharm` Community Edition 4.5.3 to display a graph with some points using `matplotlib`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([5,4,4,4,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,12,12,13],
[5,7,10,13,8,14,7,11,5,13,9,4,6,12,14,8,10,6,13,8], 'ro')

plt.plot([6,7],[8,7],'bo-')
plt.axis([0, 15, 0, 15])
plt.show()
```

Although `matplotlib` is installed properly Pycharm is not recognizing it. I'm getting this error message on running the above code in `Pycharm`

> ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: How have you installed `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you have installed python more than one and `matplotlib` library installed with python that currently not used by `Pycharm` by default. so in your python script add `#!/usr/bin/env python` 
or full path of python interpreter that has `matplotlib`.

if you are using python installed by system by default then use `python-matplotlib` if you install `python3-matplotlib` then it will create problem or vise versa . in this situation you have to  mention full path of python interpreter that you want to use .

i just installed only  `python-matplotlib` using

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

and able to run code using

```
python test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the package `python-matplotlib`

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

or for Python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem like mine.
I tested `import matplotlib` in python shell, it is OK.
But shows error in Pycharm.
This is because Pycharm don't know the path of site-packages.

1. You should add path of site-packages (for me C:\Program Files\Python
   3.5\lib\site-packages) to PATH or
2. In your code add these

   ```
   import sys    
   sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages")
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ```

I think it will help you :)